How to use provider to toggle between themes?
Actually, I want to toggle between lightTheme and darkTheme but the problem is whenever I use it, it shows the following error:

ERROR:
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/provider-6.1.2/lib/src/selector.dart:65:22:
Error: Can't declare a member that conflicts with an inherited one.
ERROR:   _Selector0State createState() => _Selector0State();
ERROR:                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ ERROR:
../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:808:13:
Context: This is the inherited member. ERROR:   State get createState;
ERROR:             ^^^^^^^^^^^ ERROR: Target kernel_snapshot_program
failed: Exception Error: Build process failed

Here, while using StatefulWidget the createState() method doesn't work, so I have to convert it into the getter one, then it works fine, but the provider shows the error.


Please send the provider code also post the full code of the This widget not just a part of it

Please don't screenshots of code or other textual content, but rather post them as actual text and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark them up. Having the content as text makes it accessible, searchable and makes it easier for folks to help you. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

Show your code; it's better to show it off so we can understand the process flow before the exception is thrown.

If your method _Selector0State or something else is a cause of exception.
Have you tried this?
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // _Selector0State or something else that is responsible for triggering 
  // the toggle function
});

